# play framework plugin not working in intellij 13.1 ultimate

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, playframework

I am using intellij idea 13.1 ultimate and play support is added in my settings -> plugin option as shown in the figure below

[image: play plugins]

but intellij still showing the errors for play functions and classes .I am also not able to run play from intellij.

[image: error in intellij]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Show us your whole controller at list  all lines  before `public class Job...`

Comment: as you say @biesior,updated my question

Comment: Did you compile this project at least once from command line ? if not `clean` it first and `compile` then refresh IDE. BTW remember that `play.api.*` is for Scala

Comment: @biesior i am compiling and running this application from command line

Comment: Which version of Play are you using? Have you tried running **idea** command?

Comment: play 2.2.1 yes i have created my project from command line and then imported in  intellij and ive also tried play idea